# Joomla 2.5 Show Module only on K2 Category not on K2 item

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I've assinged some modules to the category page but they also appear on the K2 item page.

I've tried Advanced Module Manager but it says it's not compatible with the module i was using so the Also on child item option doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem,and solved

create a hidden menu for each K2 item,
in menu manager create a new menu (name it hidden) where it will not appear in any page,
then at that hidden menu you can create a menu for each k2 item, 
and in module manger deselect that menus from menu assignment
that solution worked for me as i didnt have much k2 items

Comment: Thank you for the reply, although i don't think i'll ever go back to using Joomla it's good for anyone else with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create an override for the modules you are trying to display and wrap the whole thing in an if clause.

First copy the folder `/modules/mod_MYMODULE/tmpl` to `/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html` and rename it to the name of your module eg `/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/mod_MYMODULE`.

Then rename `default.php` to whatever (for example `k2catonly.php`) and wrap it in an if clause eg.

```
if(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view') == 'itemlist') {
    // module code
}
```

Then open said modules in your module manager and select your new sub-template (usually found in the advanced options and called "Alternative Layout".

Now your module will only display on the category. To display it on all pages but the item page wrap it in the following instead:

```
if(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view') !== 'item') {
    // module code
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this not works on me... Doesn't find my new module in "Alternative Layout"...